# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django

Am trying to develop an app for student management. Every thing seems to be working fine. but am receiving an errors at some point. If i open the list view it shows all the student, if i click a student photo it will open a detail view of that student for me, then if i click add button inside the view it will show me (NoReverseMatch at `/add_subj/3/`
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments `'('',)'` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['(?P[0-9]+)/$']` ). I want to be able to add subject to a particular id. Please need some help, am new in django.

This is the link to my models.py, views.py and urls
https://gist.github.com/AnyiLloyd/a963e9e3f52aa8f46fd7ef9a6ec0dddb

Comment: Can you isolate the region of code that may be producing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a templating error. Check the html on the page that's giving the error.

Likely there's a broken url that looks something like this: `{% url 'detail' subject.pk %}`

Comment: Thanks for the replay. this is the mage that show the detail {% url 'detail' subject.pk %}. But if i remove it, it will display and the form wont save or do anything. i thought the problem is from my views.py. The link https://gist.github.com/AnyiLloyd/a963e9e3f52aa8f46fd7ef9a6ec0dddb    thanks